# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads, promotion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/community-promotion-ads-2013)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for electronics work
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1168).

Answer (score 8):

[image: @StackElectronix]

Comment: Is this meant to resemble an "X"?

Comment: @clabacchio It's actually the favicon for the site. It was done by a very nice fellow who was a bit more artsy than electronics-y

Answer (score 7):

[image: Mathematica at Stack Exchange -- help this community grow!]

Comment: This is a new StackExchange site, still in beta, for questions about the [Mathematica system](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/).  The site still needs to grow before it can graduate.  If you are a Mathematica user, consider asking your next question at Mathematica.SE :-)

Comment: It has been instilled in me that "funnest" is not a word to the degree that I find that hard to look at. :-P

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You can complain to the original author :P  I can't argue with native speakers.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Laen's PCB order for hobbyists]

Comment: I am not sure why people dislike this, this seems like a pretty cheap way to get small order boards, someone care to explain?

Comment: Huh, I didn't even see the downvotes (not enough rep). Thanks for pointing them out for me.

Comment: it is your post, not mine. I was just saying I did not see an issue with the add.

Comment: What? I was just commenting that I didn't even see any downvotes on my post, and I was thanking you for pointing them out to me.

Comment: No worries, I just missunderstood you. Are you affiliated with OSHPark.com ?

Comment: Sorry about that :). I am not affiliated with them. I've just used them a few times (most recently yesterday) and the guy that runs it is really nice, so I thought I'd help out a bit.

Comment: Also used them. Nice stuff, nice people. Oh yeah, and the purple color is just awesome.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Lets build a goddamn Tesla museum!]