# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for electronics work
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2515).

Answer (score 31):

[image: Laen's PCB order for hobbyists]

Comment: This one didn't achieve the threshold last year for some reason, but I'll try again.

Comment: I use OSHPark when I can wait 12-21 days for my boards. It's awesome!

Comment: I just received my first order from OSH Park. I was a BatchPCB customer before. I must say the quality and turnaround time is great (for prototyping). I'm not sure I want everything purple, but it's fine!

Comment: @jyelton: I personally like the gold–on–purple :).

Comment: It seems they're offering free shipping worldwide nowadays.

Comment: @nitro2k01 Impressive, seems the service has taken off even more since I last used it (last time was over the summer). I'll have to edit the ad for 2014.

Answer (score 24):

[image: Hamsterworks FPGA Course]

Answer (score 18):

[image: EEVBlog: An off-the-cuff video blog for electronics engineers, hobbyists, hackers and makers.]

Comment: Posted with permission from Dave Jones.

Comment: nice one he has a lot of great tutorials.

Comment: This is the guy that posted the very self-aggrandizing rant about the PicKit3 versus the PicKit2.  After that fiasco his credibility is completely shot and anything he says isn't worth listening to.  It was clear he was just ranting to get more viewers.  -1 for this bozo.

Comment: @Olin You mean [the one back in 2009](http://www.eevblog.com/2009/10/21/eevblog-39-pickit-3-programmerdebugger-review/), to which Microchip actually responded?

Comment: @JYelton: Yes, that's the one.  The original video is just a rant looking for attention.  Microchip's response was awesome.  I particularly loved the part about the refurbished LEDs.  Where can I get me a batch of those for $.02 less?

Comment: @Olin I agree Dave can be a little crazy sometimes, but I don't think he was "just" seeking attention. Anyone who does video blogs has to grab attention, but I think he was genuinely perturbed by the v3 product. He's done 500+ videos, the majority of which are less ranty and more interesting.

Comment: @JYelton, were you going to post this one again for this year? I'd like to nominate it again but thought it would have been a bit rude to cut & paste your post.

Comment: @PeterJ I'll email Dave to ensure he's okay with using it again. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 16):

[image: @StackElectronix]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: I've never liked that graphic.  It actually took me a while to realize it was a non-electronics guy's idea of a chip (apparently).  The multiple notches and them being in the center of each edge make absolutely no sense.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Yes, I am sorry you dont like the graphic, but it is the add to show off the twitter, If you would post an alternative I would enjoy it, but you are blocking an add to get people more involved because you dont like the chip picture.

Comment: @Kortuk: I am not "blocking" anything, just making a comment.  I have re-read the question explaining community promotion ads a few times and still don't get it.  Ads for other SE users to make them aware of EE would make some sense, or ads in the outside world to the EE part of SE, but that's not what the question seems to be saying.  I'm having a hard time grasping who is supposed to be convinced to do what by these ads.

Comment: @OlinLathrop you might link somewhere like here: http://circuitlab.en.malavida.com/webapps/ Or if you want other people to come to EE.SE then go to their SE site and post in their version of this thread.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: All of the ads will be displayed on this site and the purpose is two-fold. Some ads will be designed to direct traffic to areas of interest pertaining directly to this site (e.g. EE's Twitter feed). Other ads will link to websites/tools/blogs/etc. that we think visitors would find interesting (that's the **Community** in Community Promotion Ads). Pureferret makes a good point: If you want to direct traffic to this site, then the way to do this would be to create an ad on another site's Community Promotion Ads meta question.

Answer (score 16):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Comment: Thanks to [Sasha](http://www.clker.com/clipart-188290.html) for placing this image in the public domain.

Comment: For those who don't recognise the reference, see [Marvin the paranoid android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_the_Paranoid_Android#Radio_and_TV_series).

Comment: Actually, I think he's more *cute* than the competitive robot ;-)

Answer (score 15):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Comment: Thanks to [Daniel T. McDonald](http://www.elfwood.com/~captainzero/GIR-2.0.2597782.html) for placing this image in the public domain.

Comment: For those who don't recognise the reference, [GIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invader_Zim#Characters) is [Invader Zim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invader_Zim)'s malfunctioning robot.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Chemistry - Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Amateur Radio]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Fritzing]

Comment: I think we need something more electronics related. **:)**

Comment: I'm OK with schematics drawn with fritzing, but I wish we could block the "virtual breadboard" things. They're basically the "schematic" equivalent of posting an image of a PCB.

Answer (score 10):

[image: What's going on? Help us find out!]

Comment: From: http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/192/187

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Comment: @MarkBoothonce they're out of beta.

Comment: @markbooth, they haven't got a community ads post though...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I think you misunderstood me - I meant that your advert for *scifi* would work as well to advertise *robotics* here. *8')

Comment: UPVOTE ME!!!!! I AM LONELY.

Answer (score 8):

[image: The online circuit editor: CircuitLab]

Comment: CircuitLab has become a commercial product since you posted this, and I don't think we should provide ads for that.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 3):

[image: SciFi & Fantasy]

Comment: I don't get it.  What is this advertising?  Who is supposed to be convinced to do what by this ad?

Comment: @Camil: It's a reference to the Star Wars death star, but that still doesn't explain the purpose of this ad.  Again, who is supposed to be convinced to do what by this ad?

Comment: @OlinLathrop the goal is to have you click it and look at scifi.SE.

Comment: @Kortuk: In that case this is a totally ineffective ad, at least on me.