# What is the origin and significance of the EE.SE logo?

Tags: support, design

No search results in the meta give me much indication. Where did the logo come from, and does it mean anything?

Comment: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/448/design-for-electronics-and-robotics

Answer (score 7):

I assume you mean our favicon and the logo that is used in our twitter ad?

[image]

The logo represents a chip, which you can see because it's black and has pads. Also, the notches are meant to make it look more chippy, although real chips have only one notch. The red thing in the middle is an LED.

The logo was made by [Jin](http://stackexchange.com/users/21721/jin), the SE designer.

Also see:

> Is this meant to resemble an "X"? – clabacchio♦ [May 29 '12 at 21:41](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/community-promotion-ads-2012#comment2862_1169)
>
> @clabacchio It's actually the favicon for the site. It was done by a very nice fellow who was a bit more artsy than electronics-y – W5VO♦ [May 30 '12 at 0:41](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/community-promotion-ads-2012#comment2864_1169)

And:

> I've never liked that graphic. It actually took me a while to realize it was a non-electronics guy's idea of a chip (apparently). The multiple notches and them being in the center of each edge make absolutely no sense. – Olin Lathrop [Dec 13 '12 at 12:40](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/community-promotion-ads-2013#comment4108_2516)